# discord.js spam command troubles

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
  bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'spam') {
        message.channel.send('spam');
        while (message.channel.send('spam')) {
            if (message.content === 'stop spam') {
                return message.channel.send('stopped');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

im still fairly new to javascript so im not sure if this is even possible the way ive been trying to do it ive looked through w3schools developers.mozilla and even a few questions that are already on here; ive tried using do while, and for loops and ive tried multiple versions of the code i have up there

the ultimate goal is if a user sends the word 'spam' the bot should continuously send the word 'spam' and keep doing so till the bot is turned off or a user sends the words 'stop spam'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some things you should know about the code you're working with:

1. `message.channel.send` returns a [`Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/promise/info), so you can't put that in a `while` loop, because you need to have something that is `true` or `false` (a `Boolean`).
2. Right now you're trying to check if a message's content is equal to `'stop spam'` while you're inside the `if-statement` checking if the content is equal to `'spam'` - So you'll never get inside the inner `if-statement`.

I would recommend practicing basic javascript a bit more, then moving to Node.js, then coming back to Discord.js - However, it might be cool for you to see a spammer work, so I wrote a some spam code you could use - check this out:

First, create a new file named `spamCtrl.js` that looks like this (see comments in code for descriptions of what's going on):

```
let spamming = false;
let spamChannel = undefined;

// spam function repeats until variable spamming is false
function spam() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        // add check to make sure discord channel exists
        if (!spamChannel)
            reject('Channel is undefined!');

        // send message on spam channel
        spamChannel.send('spam')
        .then(msg => {
            // wait 100 ms until sending next spam message
            setTimeout(() => {
                // continue spamming if spamming variable is true
                if (spamming) {
                    spam()
                    .then(resolve) // not entirely necessary, but good practice
                    .catch(console.log); // log error to console in case one shows up
                }

                // otherwise, just resolve promise to end this looping
                else {
                    resolve();
                }
            }, 100)
        })
        .catch(console.log);

    });
}

// public functions that will be used in your index.js file
module.exports = {
    // pass in discord.js channel for spam function
    setChannel: function(channel) {
        spamChannel = channel;
    },

    // set spam status (true = start spamming, false = stop spamming)
    setStatus: function (statusFlag) {
        // get current status
        let currentStatus = spamming;

        // update spamming flag
        spamming = statusFlag;

        // if spamming should start, and it hasn't started already, call spam()
        if (statusFlag && currentStatus != statusFlag) {
            spam();
        }
    },

    // not used in my commands, but you may find this useful somewhere
    getStatus: function() {
        return spamming;
    }
};
```

Next, import that file into your `index.js` file (Must be in the same directory as your `spamCtrl.js` file - unless you change the `require` statement below).

```
// in index.js file, get controller for spam messages
let spamCtrl = require('./spamCtrl');
```

Final step: In your `index.js` file (or wherever you're handling your spam commands) set up your commands (this can be renamed as you like):

```
// 2 commands together make spamming work :)
case '?SPAM':
    spamCtrl.setChannel(message.channel);
    spamCtrl.setStatus(true);
    break;
case '?STOP-SPAM':
    spamCtrl.setStatus(false);
    break;
```

Let me know if you would like any additional explanations on anything, or if you want to see some tweaks here 'n there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a variable instead. You cannot use `message.channel.send('spam')` for the while loop.

```
var spam = false;
if (message.content === 'spam') {
    if (message.author.id !== bot.user.id) { // Replace bot with the instance of your bot Client.
        spam = true;
    } else {
        if(spam) {
            message.channel.send('spam');
        }
    }
    if (message.content === 'stop spam') {
        if(spam) {
            message.channel.send('stopped');
        }
        spam = false;
    }
}
```